# Supabase error: Cancelling statement due to statement timeout

Tags: next.js, prisma, supabase

I am developing a project using Next.js, Supabase and Prisma.

After defining the data models in the `schema.prisma` file, I ran `npx prisma migrate dev` to sync the Prisma schema with the database. However, I received the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this Prisma documentation on how to run migrate dev init with cloud hosted db useful for this problem: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually

I also found prisma db push works fine sometimes without shadow database.

Another thing to check, there is an old thread in Prisma’s github issues with some other workarounds from users:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10575

Comment: `prisma db push` seems to be sufficient for SB. thanks @monica!